# MS Access SQL LIKE query from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2010, sql-like

I have this query for Ms Access and im using C# and Ole DB commands. It works on Ms Access but when I'm passing the query from C# using OleDB, nothing happened. Anyway here's my code:

SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM tblIssue WHERE  id LIKE '*2*' AND dateChecque LIKE '**'AND +
issueTo LIKE '**' AND byTheName LIKE '**' AND bankName LIKE '**' AND accountNo LIKE '**' +
AND checqueNo LIKE '**' AND amount LIKE '**' AND being LIKE '**'   AND whoDeleted LIKE '**' +
AND whyDeleted LIKE '**' AND dateCreated LIKE '**';
```

C# code

```
try
{
    DataTable newDt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter newSda = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery , conn);
    newSda.Fill(newDt);

    if (newDt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = newDt.DefaultView;
        _hasData = true;
    }
    else
    {
        _hasData = false;
    }
}
catch (Exception error)
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.ToString()); conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Nothings happening? Do you get an error message? Have you actually executed the query or just stored it in the `sqlQuery` variable?

Comment: Whe n I run the query from Ms Access, its executed, but when I used that query to C#, nothing happens. No error. Ok I will edit my code.

Comment: can you provide more code?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19051037/why-is-my-like-query-not-returning-any-records-in-microsoft-access-2013-only/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Queries performed from within the Microsoft Access application itself normally use `*` and `?` as wildcard characters for the `LIKE` operator. OleDb connections to an Access database from an external application should use the `%` and `_` wildcard characters instead. (The latter are actually the more commonly-used wildcard characters in other SQL dialects.)

Comment: Thanks! Now its working. Actually Im using % before but I changed it to * after doing some research about access.

Comment: Sorry I cant Vote Up my reputation is just 8. And someone downvote my question. :(

Comment: Wow! How come? Hehe! 
Vote up finish! :)

Comment: Here's some more wildcard references. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-wildcard-character-reference-HA010076601.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966377.aspx :

> Microsoft Jet uses partial match (or "wildcard") characters with the Like operator that are different from those used in most SQL dialects. The asterisk (*) character matches zero or more characters and is equivalent to the percent (%) character in ANSI SQL. The other Microsoft Jet partial match characters are the question mark (?), which matches any character in a single field, and the number sign (#), which matches any digit in a single field.