# asp.net oledbcommand return all rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am using Oledbconnection to connect to a Microsoft Access database, and I am using OleDbCommand to retrieve some information. I have a query in the database called retrieveInfo, which retrieves 3 rows of data. There are some duplicates in the fields but that's how it's supposed to be. My data looks like this:

```
 Name          Email
 A             A@gmail.com
 B             A@gmail.com
 B             C@gmail.com
```

My C# code behind looks like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    string query = "SELECT * FROM retrieveInfo";
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        DataTable info = new DataTable();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        info.Clear();
        dataAdapter.Fill(info);
    }
```

I ran the query retrieveInfo in MS Access and it returned 3 rows like shown above. However when I run this command using C# and loaded the data into a datatable, it only shows 2 rows. The datatable only has 1st and 2nd row. I don't know if this has anything to do with the original table properties, or is my C# code wrong? I also tried using a data reader, execute reader and using a while loop to read data. But it also only return 2 rows.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: So immediately after you do the `.Fill` is `info.Rows.Count` returning 2?

Comment: you're missing your closing `}` for your using btw.. what's your connection string look like.. check this site for how to configure [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstring.com) look for MS Access `info.Clear();` this in not even necessary..

Comment: @Gord Thompson  Yes Rows.Count only return 2.

Comment: @MethodMan   Thank you for the reminder. I have checked my connection string and it is correct. Because when I access it using query that doesnt return duplicate field it works perfectly fine. So that's why I was wondering if it has something to do with returning rows with duplicate values?

Comment: what if you set a breakpoint on this line `dataAdapter.Fill(info);` use the QuickWatch in the debugger and see if the rows are all returned when you hover over `info`

Comment: Can you post the connection string.What Jet Library you use?

Comment: @MethodMan    I have tried debugging the application using a breakpoint. After the datatable was filled I added 'info' to the watch. It only has 2 rows, but the same sql statement in access returns 3.

Comment: This sounds very odd.. I have never experienced this before..

Comment: @MichaelChi Did you ever find resolution for this issue?  I am experiencing it today.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you are using a 'LIKE' statement somewhere in retrieveInfo's definition, either in that query itself or in one of its sub-queries.  OleDbDataAdapter cannot resolve MS Access LIKE statement as it's written in Access SQL.  You need to use ANSI LIKE (see link).

[Stackoverflow Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000204/ms-access-sql-like-query-from-c-sharp)

Now I use

```
Like "oldmcdonal%" Or Like "oldmcdonal*"
```

This provides the expected result set regardless of whether it's executed in MS Access or via .net code.